# Lower bound for concentration probability of Rademacher sum

Tags: probability-theory, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails, rademacher-distribution

Suppose that $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$ are $n$, iid Rademacher random variables (equally likely to be $+1, -1$).

I would like to know what the tightest result is for the following concentration probability (for $\alpha > 0$)

$$
p_n(\alpha) := \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \right| \leq \alpha \sqrt{n}\right\}.
$$

One method I know of is via application of Hoeffding-type results, which yield something like

$$\mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \right| \leq \alpha \sqrt{n}\right\} 
= 1 - \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \right| > \alpha \sqrt{n}\right\} \geq 1 - 2e^{-\alpha^2/2}. 
$$

The issue with this result is that if $\alpha < \sqrt{2 \ln 2}$, then this result is completely uninformative (it would be better to bound from below by 0).

Thus, I would like to know if there are better quantitative results (mostly for lower bounds on $p_n(\alpha)$) available for $\alpha$ quite small (say less than $1/2$) but still bounded away from $0$. I'm mostly interested in asymptotics, so we may assume $n$ is as large as we like.

Comment: Yes, those are called "anti-concentration results" or "small ball probability" results.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer, which relies on the Central limit theorem goes like this. Since $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \dots$ is an iid sequence of random variables with variance 1 and mean zero, the central limit theorem implies that $n^{-1/2} \sum_{k \leq n} \epsilon_k$ tends in distribution to a $N(0, 1)$ random variable. Hence, 
$$
\lim_n \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i\right| \leq \alpha \sqrt{n} \right\} = \mathbf{P}\left\{N(0,1) \leq \alpha \right\} = 1 - \mathbf{P}\{N(0,1) > \alpha\} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\alpha^2/2}. 
$$
So at least asymptotically we can improve constants a bit.